# SSO between Webapp and REST API using apache shiro

Tags: java, rest, single-sign-on, cas, shiro

I'm trying to set up a SSO between a webapp and a REST API, to do this I'm using Apache Shiro + Jasig CAS but now I'm having a problem related to the authentication of the REST API.
I'm using CASRealm + CASFilter in the Webapp and trying to use the session created there to access the REST API, I've tried 2 approaches:

1. propagating the CAS service ticket from the webapp to the REST API through the request header (does not work, it says the service ticket is invalid because it belongs to another app, maybe the TGT would work)
2. store the username and password in the webapp and use them in http basic authentication (this might be a big security flaw, I'm trying to avoid it)

What other approach can I use to authenticate the user in the REST API?

I guess this is mainly an architecture issue. 
Please ask questions if you didn't understand my question (or my english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use the first CAS service as a proxy for your REST API: you could use the CAS proxy mechanism: `https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Proxy+CAS+Walkthrough`. Though, the proxy support is not available in the Shiro CAS module, you should use the **buji-pac4j** extension, here is a good discussion on this topic: `http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/Shiro-cas-proxying-td7579694.html`.

Comment: I'll try your suggestions and give you feedback later. Is the patch you submitted already included in buji-pac4j version 1.2.1?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the long absence. Your answer is being really helpful but now I'm having a problem getting the proxy ticket in the proxy application. I get the following log `INFO [org.jasig.cas.client.proxy.ProxyGrantingTicketStorageImpl] - <No Proxy Ticket found for [PGTIOU-15-d4Cm3cF2StBgXXqF4dt1-cas01.example.org].>` and `casProxyProfile.getProxyTicketFor(serviceName)` returns null. Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to say, would you mind opening a discussion on the Shiro mailing list?

Comment: I've oppened the following discussion [http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/SSO-between-Webapp-and-REST-API-using-apache-shiro-td7579861.html ]

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the OAuth2.0 configuration on CAS and then u can secure your REST services with the oauth2.0. For example u can have a rest service with oauth for user authentication. Here some usefull links.

[OAuth configuration](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Configuration+for+the+OAuth+server+support)

[Securing REST](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/10/09/securing-restful-web-services-with-oauth2/)

[OAuth and REST](http://tatiyants.com/using-oauth-to-protect-internal-rest-api/)